# Combine Multiple MsgBox to one

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine multiple msgbox but i couldnot figure out.
Here is my Code:

```
If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DailyReport").Range("F8").Value, "DCT") > 0 Then
    If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("G34").Value) Then
        MsgBox ("The Following Test is not Performed " & Sheet2.Range("E34").Value)
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("G35").Value) Then
        MsgBox ("The Following Test is not Performed " & Sheet2.Range("E35").Value)
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("G36").Value) Then
        MsgBox ("The Following Test is not Performed " & Sheet2.Range("E36").Value)
    End If
End If
```

I want to search for word `DCT` in Cell `F8` of Worksheets `DailyReport` and if it exist then I want to look at multiple cell like `G34`,`G35`,`G36`.... and if these cell are empty then display msgbox saying "The following Test is Not performed: `E34`,`E35`,`E36`...."

Let's Say if `G34` and `G35` is Empty then the msg box should display
The following Test is not Performed:

```
Cell value in E34
Cell Value in E35
```

`Msgbox` Should have continue and Cancel button

If User hit Continue Then Continue the sub

If user Hit Cancel then Exit the sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Return Combined Messages in a Message Box

```vb
Sub CombineMessages()
    
    Dim CheckCells() As Variant: CheckCells = Array("G34", "G35", "G36")
    Dim ValueCells() As Variant: ValueCells = Array("E34", "E35", "E36")
    
    Dim CheckString As String
    CheckString = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DailyReport").Range("F8").Value)
    
    Dim UntestedCount As Long, MsgString As String

    If InStr(CheckString, "DCT") > 0 Then
        Dim n As Long
        For n = LBound(CheckCells) To UBound(CheckCells)
            If IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range(CheckCells(n))) Then
                MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & "    " _
                    & CStr(Sheet2.Range(ValueCells(n)).Value)
                UntestedCount = UntestedCount + 1
            End If
        Next n
    End If
    
    If UntestedCount > 0 Then
        MsgString = "The following test" _
            & IIf(UntestedCount = 1, " is", "s are") & " not performed:" _
            & vbLf & MsgString & vbLf & vbLf & "Do you want to continue?"
        Dim Msg As Long: Msg = MsgBox(MsgString, vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
        If Msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
 
    MsgBox "Continuing...", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible: For cells that were empty  I want to put Cell value as "N/P" and Continue the sub if the user clicks on Yes. so, if G34 and G35 were empty then I would like to put cell value as "N/P" on cell G34 and G35

Comment: 1.) Try `If CStr(Sheet2.Range(CheckCells(n)).Value) = "Not Performed" Then`. If you need case insensitivity, then use `If StrComp(CStr(Sheet2.Range(CheckCells(n)).Value), "Not Performed", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`.

Comment: 2.) Use `Sheet2.Range(CheckCells(n)).Value = "N/P"` right below `If IsEmpty(...) Then`.

Comment: But this will put N/P whether the user click on both yes and No

Comment: I guess that would require quite some changes. Best ask another question where you'll accurately describe your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to look at multiple cell like G34,G35,G36....

> if these cell are empty then display msgbox saying "The following Test is Not performed: E34,E35,E36...."

`G34,G35,G36....` Looks like this range is dynamic? Or will it always be these 3? And if it is dynamic then how are you deciding the range. For example why `G34` and not `G1`? Or till where do you want to check? Till last cell in `G`? All this will decide how you write a **concise vba code**. I am going to assume that you want to check till last cell in column `G`. In case it is say from `G34` to say `G60`(*just an example*), then change the `For Next` Loop from `For i = 34 To lRow` to `For i = 34 To 60`

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim CellAddress As String
    
    If InStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DailyReport").Range("F8").Value, "DCT") > 0 Then
        
        With Sheet2
            '~~> Find last row in Col G
            lRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            '~~> Check the range for blank cells
            For i = 34 To lRow
                If Len(Trim(.Range("G" & i).Value2)) = 0 Then
                    CellAddress = CellAddress & "," & "E" & i
                End If
            Next i
        End With
        
        '~~> Check if any addresses were found
        If CellAddress <> "" Then
            CellAddress = Mid(CellAddress, 2)
            
            Dim ret As Integer
            
            '~~> Ask user. There is no CONTINUE button. Use YES/NO
            ret = MsgBox("The following Test is Not performed:" & _
                          vbNewLine & CellAddress & vbNewLine & _
                          "Would you like to continue?", vbYesNo)
            If ret = vbYes Then
                '~~> Do what you want
            Else
                '~~> You may not need the else/exit sub part
                '~~> Depending on what you want to do
                Exit Sub
            End If
            '
            '
            '~~> Rest of the code
            '
            '
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```